# How to model a Tree based database using MongoDB?

Tags: sql, mongodb, cassandra, rdbms, nosql

I have an application that will store data in a an entity called Department.For this department i will have **SubDepartment1**,**SubDepartment2** and **SubDepartment3**
Now,i want to store massive data in database.those data are students.
In RDBMS.the modelisation is simple.Just having one Entity called department and the 3 supdepartment will inherit from the father department.
Can you please tell me how to model this in MongoDB?

I know subCollection but it does not look good because i will have also a collection called department that i will be able to store data in it.

Answer (score 1):

mongodb  have a extensive document about model tree data [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/)